# Update price for a product on custom checkbox selection WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was trying to create something which will update the product price before customer adds the product to cart.

I have created a custom `checkbox`. What I want to do is, if the `checkbox` is checked then update the price to something else.

How do I do that?